# Weird django css behaviour

Tags: css, django, apache

I have a site made with django on one server, and now I am trying to copy it to another one. On the original site all the CSS works fine, but on the new site it is bugged.

The file is located at `myhost/static/styles.css`. On both hosts the css is accessable with a browser (so it should get served fine).

On the new host, If I check it in the Google chrome resources inspector it get loaded. It also starts working for the current page, if I edit a single line in Chrome and press enter (So it gets reloaded).

Otherwise I'd think it would be a client issue, but it works fine on the other host.

Comment: Is there any error log?

Comment: I don't think I saw anything in httpd error_log, or in the console when trying with the django dev server

Comment: which application server static files? which web server? if nginx, how server static files?

Comment: I have tried apache httpd (it is used on the working host), and the manage.py's development server